# Owl Importing Error gives parse error in Protege

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

Please any body help me out.It is not loading into protege giving parse error.

Please give me the solution how i can remove this error from my ontology file.

```
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY xsd 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'>
<!ENTITY link 'http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.owl#'>
<!ENTITY xlink 'http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xlink-2003-12-31.owl#'>
<!ENTITY xbrli 'http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.owl#'>
<!ENTITY us-gaap-ci 'http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2008/07/us-gaap-ci-2005-02-28.owl#'>
<!ENTITY usfr-mda 'http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2008/07/usfr-mda-2004-08-15.owl#'>
<!ENTITY adbe 'http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/bizontos/xbrl-edgar/adbe-20080530.owl#'>

]>
```

OWL ontology generated by the xsd2owl XML Style Sheet (http://rhizomik.net/redefer)

```
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="PrepaidExpensesOtherCurrentAssets">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="InvestmentLeaseReceivable">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TradeOtherPayables">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AccruedRestructuringExpensesCurrent">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AccruedRestructuringExpensesNonCurrent">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="InvestmentGainLoss">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CashDividendsDeclaredPerShare">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="StockBasedCompensation">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ProvisionRecoveryOfLossesOnReceivables">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ExcessTaxBenefitsStockBasedCompensationOperating">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AcquiredIncompleteTechnology">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="NetGainsLossesSalesImpairmentInvestments">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ChangesTradeOtherPayables">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="MaturitiesShortTermInvestments">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="PurchasesLongTermInvestmentsOtherAssets">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ExcessTaxBenefitsStockBasedCompensationFinancing">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="StockIssuedAndOptionsAssumedAcquisition">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceCompensatoryStockAdditionalPaidCapital">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ReissuanceTreasuryStockEmployeeStockPurchaseOptionPlanAdditionalPaidCapital">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ChangeOtherComprehensiveIncomeOrLossNetofTaxesOtherAccumulatedComprehensiveIncome">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceCompensatoryStockTreasuryStockShares">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;sharesItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceCompensatoryStockTreasuryStockValue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TreasuryStockAcquiredValueVotingRightsDividendsTreasuryStockValue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ReissuanceTreasuryStockEmployeeStockPurchaseOptionPlanTreasuryStockShares">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;sharesItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ReissuanceTreasuryStockEmployeeStockPurchaseOptionPlanTreasuryStockValue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceCompensatoryStockTotalShareholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ChangeOtherComprehensiveIncomeOrLossNetofTaxesTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TreasuryStockAcquiredValueVotingRightsDividendsTotalShareholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ReissuanceTreasuryStockEmployeeStockPurchaseOptionPlanTotalShareholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TotalComprehensiveIncomeNetOfTaxesTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockUnderStockCompensationPlanCommonShares">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;sharesItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockUnderStockCompensationPlanCommonStockAmount">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockForAcquisitionShares">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;sharesItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockForAcquisitionCommonSharesAmount">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockUnderStockCompensationPlansAdditionalPaidInCapital">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockForAcquisitionAdditioanlPaidInCapital">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockUnderStockCompensationPlansSharesTreasuryShares">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;sharesItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="DeferredCompensationAmortizationAdditionalPaidInCapital">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockUnderStockCompensationPlansTreasuryStockValue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockForAcquisitionTreasuryStockShares">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;sharesItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockForAcquisitionTreasuryStockAmount">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockUnderStockCompensationPlansTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="IssuanceOfCommonStockAndReissuanceOfTreasuryStockForAcquisitionTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="DeferredCompensationAmortizationTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TaxBenefitFromEmployeeStockOptionPlans">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="StockCompensation">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="DividendsDeclaredTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TaxBenefitFromEmployeeStockOptionPlansTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="StockCompensationTotalStockholdersEquity">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="UnrealizedGainLossAvailableForSaleSecuritiesNetOfTaxes">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="InvestmentMadeInLeaseReceivable">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ProductRevenueDividedByTotalRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ProductRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodProductRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ServicesSupportRevenueDividedByTotalRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ServiceSupportRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodServicesSupportRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TotalRevenueChangeDividedByPriorYearTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CreativeSolutionsRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CreativeSolutionsRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CreativeSolutionsRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodCreativeSolutionsRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="KnowledgeWorkerSolutionsRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="KnowledgeWorkerRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="KnowledgeWorkerRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodKnowledgeWorkerRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="EnterpriseSolutionsRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodEnterpriseSolutionsRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="EnterpriseSolutionsRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="EnterpriseSolutionsRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="MobileDeviseSolutionsRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="MobileDeviceSolutionsRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="MobileDeviceSolutionsRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="MobileDeviceSolutionsRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodMobileDeviceSolutionsRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="OtherRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="OtherRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodOtherRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="OtherRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AmericasRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AmericasRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AmericasRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodAmericasRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AsiaRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodAsiaRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AsiaRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AsiaRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ProductCostRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ProductCostRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodProductCostRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ServiceSupportCostRevenuePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ServiceSupportCostRevenueChangeDividedByPriorPeriodServiceSupportCostRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TotalCostRevenueChangeDividedByPriorYearTotalCostRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CostProductRevenueFluctuationDueToIncreasedDecreasedAmortizationOfPurchasedTechnology">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CostProductRevenueFluctuationDueToIncreasedCostSalesDueToShrinkWrapRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CostProductRevenueFluctuationDueToDecreasedLocalizationCostsRelatedToOurProductLaunches">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CostProductRevenueFluctuationDueToIncreasedRoyaltyForLicensedTechnologies">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CostProductRevenueFluctuationDueToDecreasedIncreasedExcessAndObsoleteInventory">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CostProductRevenueFluctuationDueToIncreasedDecreasedLocalizationCostsRelatedToOurProductLaunches">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="CostProductRevenueFluctuationDueToVariousInsignificantItems">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TotalCostProductRevenueFluctuation">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ResearchDevelopmentExpenseChangeDividedByPriorPeriodResearchDevelopmentExpense">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="ResearchDevelopmentExpensePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDFluctuationsDueToIncreasedCompensationRelatedBenefitsHeadcountGrowthMacromediaAcquisitionHigherIncentiveCompensationAmortizationDeferredStockCompensationAcquisitionMacromediaStockbasedCompensationCostsAdoptingSFAS123R">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDChangesDueIncreasedCompensationRelatedBenefitsHeadcountGrowthHigherIncentiveCompensation">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDChangesDueIncreasedFacilityCostAcquisitionMacroMedia">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDChangesDueIncreasedUseContractors">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDChangesDueIncreasedRepairsMaintenance">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDChangesDueIncreasedPurchasesEquipmentSoftwareLicences">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDChangesDueIncreasedVariousIndividuallyInsignificantItems">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingExpenseChangeDividedByPriorPeriodSalesMarketingExpense">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingExpensePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingChangesDueIncreasedCompensationRelatedBenefitsHeadcountGrowthMacromediaAcquisitionHigherIncentiveCompensationAmortizationDeferredStockCompensationAcquisitionMacromediaStockbasedCompensationCostsAdoptingSFAS123R">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingChangesDueIncreasedCompensationRelatedBenefitsHeadcountGrowthHigherIncentiveCompensation">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingChangesDueIncreasedContractorCosts">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingChangesDueIncreasedProfessionalFees">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingChangesDueIncreasedFacilityCostsAcqusitionMacromedia">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingChangesDueIncreasedMarketingSpendingProductLaunchesOverallMarketingEffortsIncreaseRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingChangesDueVariousIndividuallyInsignificantItems">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RDTotalChange">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="SalesMarketingTotalChange">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GAndAExpenseChangeDividedByPriorPeriodGAndAExpense">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAPercentageTotalRevenues">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedCompensationRelatedBenefitsHeadcountGrowthMacromediaAcquisitionHigherIncentiveCompensationAmortizationDeferredStockCompensationAcquisitionMacromediaStockbasedCompensationCostsAdoptingSFAS123R">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedCompensationRelatedBenefitsHeadcountGrowthHigherIncentiveCompensation">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedDecreasedLegalFees">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedProfessionalFees">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedDepreciationAmortization">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedRepairsMaintenance">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedContractorFees">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueIncreasedProvisionBadDebts">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueDecreasedLegalFees">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandAChangesDueVariousIndividuallyInsignificantItems">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GandATotalChange">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="RestructuringExpensesPercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="AmortizationPurchasedTechnologyPercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="InvestmentGainLossChangeDividedByPriorYearInvestmentGainLoss">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="InvestmentGainLossPercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="InterestOtherIncomeChangeDividedByPriorYearInterestOtherIncome">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="InterestOtherIncomePercentageOfTotalRevenue">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="TotalNonOperatingIncomeChangeDividedByPriorYearTotalNonOperatingIncome">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;pureItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="NetGainsLossesInvestmentsAdobeVenturesCostMethodInvestment">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="WriteDownsOtherThanTemporaryDeclinesValueMarketableEquitySecurities">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GainsSaleShortTermInvestments">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="GainsSaleEquityInvestments">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&xbrli;item"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xbrli;monetaryItemType"/>
</rdf:Property>
```

Comment: You haven't shown a complete RDF/XML document, so we can't load it and try it out, and you haven't shown us what the parse error is, so we can't even *guess* what it might be.  Please show a complete RDF/XML document, and show the error, in the question.

Comment: I stand partially corrected:  I went to edit a bit in the post, and I see that you've pasted the whole RDF/XML document, but you didn't mark it as code. Please select it and press Ctrl-K, or click the braces button in the editor.  Even so, it's too large to post as question.  I couldn't save the edit because the post was too many characters.  Try removing things from the RDF/XML document until you find the minimal amount that still causes the parse error, and show that.  Then we can probably diagnose it.

Answer (score 1):

The opening `rdf:RDF` element isn't visible in the question, because you didn't mark it as code, and the post is too big if you try.  However, if you look at the `rdf:RDF` element, it 's this:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns: link ="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.owl#"
     xmlns: xlink="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xlink-2003-12-31.owl#"
     xmlns:xbrli ="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.owl#"
     xmlns:us-gaap-ci ="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2008/07/us-gaap-ci-2005-02-28.owl#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns: usfr-mda="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2008/07/usfr-mda-2004-08-15.owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:adbe="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/bizontos/xbrl-edgar/adbe-20080530.owl#">
```

Those namespace declarations in the first, second, and sixth lines have spaces where they don't belong:

```xml
xmlns: link ="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.owl#"
xmlns: xlink="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xlink-2003-12-31.owl#"
xmlns: usfr-mda="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2008/07/usfr-mda-2004-08-15.owl#"
```

They need to be

```xml
xmlns:link ="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.owl#"
xmlns:xlink="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2007/11/xlink-2003-12-31.owl#"
xmlns:usfr-mda="http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2008/07/usfr-mda-2004-08-15.owl#"
```